# BlueTooth connection faliure

Tags: c++, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

**Environment**

---

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Standard USB BlueTooth dongle
- C++
- BlueZ
- Running as root

**Problem description**

---

While hcitool & sdptool properly operate, my code fail connecting to SDP with errno == 2 ( ENOENT ), the following is the failing code:

```
m_pSDPSession = sdp_connect(BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, SDP_RETRY_IF_BUSY | SDP_WAIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Why do I get 'sdp_connect' failing? how can I have that resolved ?

Comment: Have you started bluetoothd with --compat flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` and includ the flag in the ExecStart option.

`ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat`

Then

`$ systemctl daemon-reload`

`$ systemctl restart bluetooth.service`

Answer (score 0):

As Shravan40 has indicated, adding '--compat' @ 'bluetooth.service' resolved the problem